# Why isn't the value set in the constructor

Tags: c#

Given the class

```
public class B
{
  public bool flag = false;

  public B()
  {
  }
}
```

When I initialize it with the line

```
  var jjj = new B(){flag = true};
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the constructor B(), *flag* is false.  I expected it to be true because I called "flag = true" when I initialized it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax that the OP is using to set the `flag` variable does so outside of the constructor.

Answer (score 9):

That syntax is equivalent to this:

```
var temp = new B();
temp.flag = true;
var jjj = temp;
```

So in the constructor, `flag` is still `false`, and is set from the outside afterwards.

This is not special syntax to *inject* more code into a constructor, it all happens afterwards.

Note that it is *not* equivalent to this:

```
var jjj = new B();
jjj.flag = true;
```

While in this case it might not matter, but if `jjj` was a field or a property instead, you would potentially expose an object you're not done configuring early. As such, a temporary variable is constructed to hold your object while it is being initialized, and only afterwards is the object stored into its intended destination.

Here is some more information about object initializers:

- [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)
- [How to: Initialize Objects by using an Object Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)
- [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

---

**Addendum**: As mentiond by @Tim in the comments, if you really want a constructor that initialized `flag` you should add an overloaded constructor with the right parameter:

```
public B(bool flagValue)
{
    flag = flagValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a constructor like :

```
public class B
{
  public bool flag = false;

  public B()
  {
  }

  public B(bool Flag)
  {
    flag = Flag;
  }
}
```

Then try to call it like :

```
var jjj = new B(true);
```

Comment: you didn't answer the question

Comment: @Selman22 I just answered what I knew about the question. I think this was an effort from my side to help OP as much as possible. Also I am not a great developer. I am learning C# and my intention is to help people whereever I can.

Comment: But in this question the emphasis seems to be really on "Why" and not "Find me a workaround".

Comment: Ok then I don't know the answer